# How to set spacing and/or padding on Shopify Polaris ButtonGroup

Tags: shopify, spacing, polaris

I've checked the [documentation](https://polaris.shopify.com/components/button-group) and there is a prop called "spacing" for the ButtonGroup component in Shopify Polaris. It has "spacing" listed as the type to pass in (compared to boolean, text, etc.). I've tried passing in:

```
"1px"
{1}
{"1px"}
{"1"}
```

But none of these values change the spacing. I can't find any "spacing" type other than the css attribute for text-spacing which would have accepted pixels at the very least.

Regardless of spacing, the real issue is that the Polaris ButtonGroup component changes the height of the title/heading of the IndexTable (toggles when a checkbox is selected).

[image]

[image]

If it is helpful, here is the code that sets up the functionality for this.

```
 <IndexTable
            resourceName={resourceName}
            itemCount={QRCodes.length}
            selectedItemsCount={
              allResourcesSelected ? "ALL" : selectedResources.length
            }
            onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}
            headings={
              selectedResources.length > 0
                ? [
                    {
                      title: (
                        <ButtonGroup spacing="1px">
                          {" "}
                          <Button>Cancel</Button>
                          <Button>Save</Button>
                        </ButtonGroup>
                      ),
                    },
                  ]
                : [
                    { title: "Title" },
                    { title: "Status" },
                    { title: "Date created" },
                  ]
            }
            loading={loading}
          >
            {rowMarkup}
          </IndexTable>
```

If you go to the list of products on Shopify, it does not do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This answers the overall issue of providing bulk action items but the spacing specifically has yet to be discovered. There is a prop in TableIndex called bulkActions that is supposed to be used rather than creating a conditional like I had in my code.

```
<IndexTable
            resourceName={resourceName}
            itemCount={QRCodes.length}
            selectedItemsCount={
              allResourcesSelected ? "ALL" : selectedResources.length
            }
            bulkActions={[
              {
                content: "Import file",
                onAction: handleImportedAction,
              },
              {
                content: "Export file",
                onAction: handleExportedAction,
              },
            ]}
            onSelectionChange={handleSelectionChange}
            headings={[
              { title: "Title" },
              { title: "Status" },
              { title: "Date created" },
            ]}
            loading={loading}
          >
            {rowMarkup}
          </IndexTable>
```

This fixes my issue, although I am still curious as to how you would set spacing in the button group if anyone knows the answer. Hopefully someone finds this useful if they run into the same issue.